Insert array to mysql, but add other mysql-based value to each new row before insert
I have a table 'images' like this:



ProductId
SortOrder
Source




1
1
source.com/234/


1
2
source.com/675/


2
1
source.com/7698/


2
2
source.com/678/


2
3
source.com/7456/



In one mysql query, I want to insert multiple rows. But, most importantly, I want to populate the next SortOrder for each row(starting at the last one for that ProductId).
For example, I would love to be able to do:
const values = [
    [2,'source.com/456546', @max_sort_order := @max_sort_order + 1],
    [2,'source.com/237675', @max_sort_order := @max_sort_order + 1]
]

const query = "SET @max_sort_order := (SELECT COALESCE(MAX( SortOrder ), 1) FROM images i WHERE ProductId = 2);INSERT INTO images (ProductId, Source, SortOrder) VALUES ?"

connection.query({sql: query, timeout: 40000, values: [values]...

Which would ideally result in the following new rows:



ProductId
SortOrder
Source




2
4
source.com/456/


2
5
source.com/275/



But I can't put that @max_sort_order variable in the values, due to it being prepared values(I think).
Any idea on how to be go about this?

You can't refer to MySQL variables in JavaScript.

The simplest solution is secondary autoincremented column in MyISAM table:
CREATE TABLE images (
    ProductId INT,
    SortOrder INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Source VARCHAR(160),
    PRIMARY KEY (ProductId, SortOrder)
    ) ENGINE = MyISAM; 
INSERT INTO images VALUES 
(1, 1,  'source.com/234/'),
(1, 2,  'source.com/675/'),
(2, 1,  'source.com/7698/'),
(2, 2,  'source.com/678/'),
(2, 3,  'source.com/7456/');
SELECT * FROM images;




ProductId
SortOrder
Source




1
1
source.com/234/


1
2
source.com/675/


2
1
source.com/7698/


2
2
source.com/678/


2
3
source.com/7456/



INSERT INTO images (ProductId, Source) VALUES
(2,'source.com/456546'),
(2,'source.com/237675');
SELECT * FROM images;




ProductId
SortOrder
Source




1
1
source.com/234/


1
2
source.com/675/


2
1
source.com/7698/


2
2
source.com/678/


2
3
source.com/7456/


2
4
source.com/456546


2
5
source.com/237675



fiddle

Does the PRIMARY KEY (ProductId, SortOrder) part specify that SortOrder will auto-increment based on ProductId?

Also, after I set SortOrder as auto-increment and create the index with ProductId, will I be able to update 2 rows, and switch their SortOrder without running into an error?(For example, when a user wants to switch the order of 2 images.)

@CutlerRickel Does the PRIMARY KEY (ProductId, SortOrder) part specify that SortOrder will auto-increment based on ProductId? Correct. will I be able to update 2 rows, and switch their SortOrder without running into an error? Yes. You'd use UPDATE with any common algorithm which swaps two values inplace without additional memory, or use intermediate UDV. The only point - intermediate value should not present in the table, so negative value is preferred.

You'll have to do the logic in JavaScript, not MySQL.
You can get MAX(SortOrder) for all the productIDs in one call. Then you can fill in the incrementing SortOrder fields in the values array, and do a bulk insert for all of them.
const values = [
    [2,'source.com/456546', 0],
    [2,'source.com/237675', 0]
];

// Create object whose keys are the unique ProductID values.
const pidMap = Object.fromEntries(values.map(([pid]) => [pid, 0]));
const unique_pids = Object.keys(pidMap);
const placeholders = unique_pids.map(_ => '?').join(',');
const max_query = `SELECT ProductID, MAX(SortOrder) AS so FROM images WHERE ProductID IN (${placeholders}) GROUP BY ProductID`;
connection.query(max_query, unique_pids, function(err, result) {
    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }
    // Fill in the values of the object
    result.foreach(({ProductID: pid, so: max}) => pidMap[pid] = max);
    // Update the SortOrder fields in the values array with incrementing numbers
    values.forEach(val => val[2] = pidMap[++val[0]]);
    connection.query('INSERT INTO images (ProductID, Source, SortOrder) VALUES ?', values, function(err, result) { ... });
});


Thank you. I may be wrong, but doesn't mysql return an array of objects, which would make the [pid, max] destructuring on this line not work? result.foreach(([pid, max]) => pidMap[pid] = max);

You're right, I was thinking of Python, which returns tuples.
